# Apache Sqoop - addtowar.sh not found

Tags: sqoop

I just now downloaded the Sqoop installation file `sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop100.tar.gz`. I am not able to find the file `addtowar.sh` in it. I am following the installation instructions from here - https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.1/Installation.html . The following is the listing of the `bin` directory.

```
hduser@system:~/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop100/bin$ ls -ltr
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser2 hadoop 1361 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser2 hadoop 3439 Oct 18  2013 sqoop.sh
```

Am I missing something here or are the installations instructions not updated properly?

Answer (score 3):

You may refer to the docs of  the version you are using.
For 1.99.3 Refer the below link
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct answer but I have been tracking this down and it seems addtowar.sh has been removed (I am also using 1.99.3) in favor of adding hadoop jar directories into catalina.properties under common.loader line. However I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely follow the 1.99.3 documentation:
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html

But they fail to mention in that documentation that you need to add *all* of the libraries for Hadoop to the common.loader variable in catalina.properties.

To get the sqoop client working, I had to add the following to catalina.properties:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,/Users/bone/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,/Users/bone/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar,/Users/bone/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar,/Users/bone/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar,/Users/bone/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar
```

In my case, /Users/bone/tools/hadoop was a complete install of hadoop-2.4.0.